# The test for the protection of intel VT-d for OS

Tags: linux, testing, linux-kernel, intel

For now, I want to do a test to make sure that what does VT-d protect, the kernel or the memory? So, I need some tools and suggestions. Does someone have ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VT-d is an IOMMU.  It allows the bus interconnect to remap the "address space" of I/O devices.  The big use case is mapping hardware devices into the I/O space of a virtual guest machine (i.e. one implemented using VT-x) such that the hardware accesses cannot "see" any memory owned by the host OS.  In that sense it protects the the "kernel and the memory".  Beyond that you'll need to ask a more specific question.